# configuring sendmail sender address

Tags: nginx, sendmail

Just finished installing sendmail and was able to successfully send an email from the command line. However, the sender address was from root@EquinoX. I want to be able to change this so that the sender is from admin@mydomain.com. How do I do this?

I have changed my /etc/mail/local-host-names
so that the only entry it has now is mydomain.com
I have setup a A record, so that mydomain.com points to the server

UPDATE:
When I restart sendmail I got   `hostname: Name or service not known,` why is this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think typically people use the "-f" parameter for example:

```
sendmail -f me@mydomain.com
```

Comment: this means that you can set to send from any domain you wish, even if you don't own that domain?

Comment: Yup. Though an intelligent receiver can look at the headers and figure out that it didn't really come from the domain you indicated, but most people won't bother.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this using the -f switch e.g.

```
sendmail -f user@domain.com
```

This will let you set the from address.

Comment: is there a way to set this up automatically